# C++ At() function of class string Access violetion

Tags: c++

this code throw me an Access violation error

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    printf("%s",a.at(1));
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this line because this function gave me problem with a larger program and i want to figure out what the problem really is...
thanks !

Comment: What if the string `a`  is 1 char long?

Comment: @wesley.mesquita: Then you should get a well-defined exception (which, in this case, would terminate the program since it's not handled), not an access violation.

Comment: Sorry, I got a std::out_of_range here. I misread the author comment.

Answer (score 7):

The immediate problem is that `"%s"` requires a pointer to a C-style string as its corresponding argument. `a.at(1)` is a single character, not a pointer, so you have undefined behaviour when it's misinterpreted as a pointer. You want `"%c"` to print a character.

The more general problem is the use of non-typesafe C functions. In C++, you could use a typesafe output stream:

```
cout << a.at(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` `at` returns a `char` type. Using the `%s` format specifier for a `char` type will give you *undefined behaviour*. **Boom!**

Two things:

1) Check the size of the string before accessing elements using `at`: `at(1)` is accessing the *second* character of the string as the indexing is zero based.

2) Use the correct format specifier in `printf`: `printf("%c", a.at(1))`

Answer (score 2):

`at()` doesn't return a string, it returns a character. `%s` is trying to interpret that character as a (very invalid) pointer.

Try:

```
printf("%c", a.at(1));
```

(assuming `a` is at least two characters long).

Answer (score 1):

The printf function expect a char pointer and you give a char. The char value gets interpreted as an address and it is wrong.

If you only want to print a single char, use:

```
printf("%c", a.at(1))
```

provided your string is at least 2 characters long.